# HTML Helper Method For Generating Many Dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following view:

```
@model Entities.Models.Tournament

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Game"))
{        
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Team</label></td>
            <td><label>Points Brought To Tournament</label></td>
        </tr>
        @{
            const int maxNumOfTeams = 8;
            for (int i = 0; i < maxNumOfTeams; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("SelectedTeams[" + i + "].TeamId", Model.Teams, "Please select:")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("SelectedTeams[" + i + "].Points", "", new { type = "number" })</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>    
    <input type="submit" value="Create game" />
}
```

Is there a more elegant/"best practice" way of generating 8 dropdowns which are then used to build a `List<T>` and send it to an action method using HTTP Post?

The way I am doing it now seems messy as I have to build the dropdown's html ID string using concatenation and the `i` variable.

Here is the model:

```
public class Tournament
{
    //This is populated with teams from the DB and then used in the view to allow the user to select a team
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Teams { get; set; } 

    //This represents the teams the user selected
    public List<TeamWithPointsBroughtForward> SelectedTeams { get; set; }
}

public class TeamWithPointsBroughtForward
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the controller and action method:

```
public class GameController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Index(Tournament tournament)
    {            
        Game game = new Game();
        //TODO: set up the game object based on the tournament settings

        return View(game);
    }
}
```